# AnalysisException, pyspark cannot resolve variables inside dataframe query

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have below a pyspark script line here,

```
df_output = df.select("*",$checkcol) 
df_output.show()
```

It works fine by hardcoding the variable,
but when parametrized it throws an error saying,

> **pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'cannot resolve \'`"*", F.....**

where `checkcol` is an variable with value like below,

checkcol -

```
F.when(F.col("colA")=='null',"Yes").otherwise(date_validation_udf("colA")).alias("colA_DateCheck"),
F.when(F.col("colB")=='null',"Yes").otherwise(date_validation_udf("colB")).alias("colB_DateCheck"),F.when(F.col("colC")=='null',"Yes").otherwise(date_validation_udf("colC")).alias("colC_DateCheck"),
F.when(F.col("colD")=='null',"Yes").otherwise(num_check_udf("colD")).alias("colD_NumCheck"),F.when(F.col("colE")=='null',"Yes").otherwise(num_check_udf("colE")).alias("colE_NumCheck"),
F.when(F.col("colF")=='null',"Yes").otherwise(num_check_udf("colF")).alias("colF_NumCheck"),F.when(F.col("colG")=='null',"Yes").otherwise(num_check_udf("colG")).alias("colG_NumCheck")
```

Comment: what is this syntax `$checkcol` ? is it shell ?

Comment: need to execute it in pyspark script.. by calling that variable in it..

Comment: the `$` syntax is not python. Assuming `checkcol` is a `list`, I *think* what you're after is `df_output = df.select(*[df.columns + checkcol])`

Comment: no its a string..     df_w_output = df.select(*[df.columns + CheckCol])
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_output = df.withColumn("colA",
                          F.when(F.col("colA")=='null',"Yes").otherwise(date_validation_udf("colA")).alias("colA_DateCheck"))
              .withColumn("colB",
                          F.when(F.col("colB")=='null',"Yes").otherwise(date_validation_udf("colB")).alias("colB_DateCheck"),F.when(F.col("colC")=='null',"Yes").otherwise(date_validation_udf("colC")).alias("colC_DateCheck"),)
              ...

df_output.show()
```

**EDIT:**

to pass those statement as one variable to select, try this:

```
checkcol = (F.when(F.col("colA") == 'null', "Yes").otherwise(date_validation_udf("colA")).alias("colA_DateCheck"),
            F.when(F.col("colB") == 'null', "Yes").otherwise(date_validation_udf("colB")).alias("colB_DateCheck"),
            F.when(F.col("colC") == 'null', "Yes").otherwise(date_validation_udf("colC")).alias("colC_DateCheck"),
            F.when(F.col("colD") == 'null', "Yes").otherwise(num_check_udf("colD")).alias("colD_NumCheck"),
            F.when(F.col("colE") == 'null', "Yes").otherwise(num_check_udf("colE")).alias("colE_NumCheck"),
            F.when(F.col("colF") == 'null', "Yes").otherwise(num_check_udf("colF")).alias("colF_NumCheck"),
            F.when(F.col("colG") == 'null', "Yes").otherwise(num_check_udf("colG")).alias("colG_NumCheck"))


df_output =  df.select(
          '*', 
           *checkcol
)
```

Comment: Hi it works fine by hard coding it directly.. but i wanted to pass those statement as an variable to it.

Comment: hi @Amine, still getting error like, df_w_output = df.select( '*',*CheckCol) py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col.
: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: Hi @Amine, actually im getting the checkcol values from a for loop by appending it.. like,   for i,j in zip(date_data,range(Date_Count)):
  if j==(Date_Count-1):
   Check='F.when(F.col("'+i+'")=='+"'null',"+'"Yes").otherwise(date_validation_udf("'+i+'")).alias("'+i+'_DateCheck")'
  else:
   Check='F.when(F.col("'+i+'")=='+"'null',"+'"Yes").otherwise(date_validation_udf("'+i+'")).alias("'+i+'_DateCheck"),'
  CheckCol+=Check . if i execute it by directly creating a variable as u mentioned above it works.. but it fails when it picks the value from the loop. but both values remains the same.